# Beautifulsoup extraction

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here is the html code:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="brands/acapulco-gold/141120">Acapulco Gold</a></li>
   <li><a href="brands/adam-lister/141223">Adam Lister</a></li>
   <li><a href="brands/adidas-x-raf-simons/125513">adidas x RAF SIMONS</a></li>
```

I want to extract the brands like `10Deep`, `Acapulco Gold`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and get all `a` elements with `href` attribute value starting with `brands` located directly inside `li` which is located directly inside `ul`:

```
for link in soup.select("ul > li > a[href^=brands]"):
    print link.get_text()
```

Comment: there are too many "li" in the html code, the only way to find the right answer is to find all "<li><a". How can we do that? thanks

Comment: what if I want to extract information like"brands/acapulco-gold/141120", how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do it with Beautifulsoup but while waiting for an other answer... You can read each lines and retrieve the text that you want

```
import urllib
import re

source = urllib.urlopen("https://www.jackthreads.com/ca/brands")
lines = source.readlines()

brand  = []
for link in lines[1797:2121]:
  find = re.findall(r'<li><a href="brands[^>]*?>(.*?)</a>', link)
  if len(find) > 0:
    brand.append(find[0])

print(brand[0:12])
#>['10Deep', 'Acapulco Gold', 'Adam Lister', 'AdNArt', 'Afends', 'Akomplice', 'Akribos XXIV', 'Alistare', 'Alpha Beta', 'Alpha Industries', 'Altamont', 'Alternative']
```

Comment: I tried, but find all "li"is not enough, since it's only a part of all html code. But, if we can find out all"<li><a",we can get the right result. How can we do that?thanks

Comment: hi Artanis, I update my answer but I don't fully understand your last comment. could you update your question than to make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: Hi Popouche, thanks for help. Tha website is https://www.jackthreads.com/brands, I am trying to extract all the brands here. I saw the html code and found out, all brands are with the head of "<li><a"

Comment: I used ctrl+f to find out if i can located the brands. Turns out if I find  "<li><a", I will get the right answer. So I was wondering, if I can use beautifulsoup to find all  "<li><a"

Comment: I tried with your method, but get more output than I want. And why there are "u"s in front of all the brands?can we get results without "u"s?

Comment: @ArtanisWong the answer I've provided is looking exactly for `ul -> li -> a` constructions on the page.

Comment: @ArtanisWong This was a tricky question :) you should re-title this post or re-sentence your question. No need to add your url but you should say that the `<li>`'s are loaded dynamically (with a js script as react.js or handlebars).

Comment: I fixed it, but a new question come. I want to input the result into a txt file.Here is my code:

Comment: def grabHref(url,localfile):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    html = unicode(html,'gb2312','ignore').encode('utf-8','ignore')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for link in soup.select("ul > li > a[href^=brands/]"):
        allBrands = link.get_text()
        print allBrands
        myfile = open(localfile,'wb')
        myfile.write(allBrands)
        myfile.write('\r\n')
        myfile.close()

Comment: def main():
    url = "https://www.jackthreads.com/brands"
    localfile = 'Brands.txt'
    grabHref(url,localfile)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

Comment: why I can see all the brands in console, but in the txt file, only the last brand in it?